# Automatically update two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL so take it easy on me.
I have two tables with the same number of rows. These two tables share columns whose attributes need to be the same. What O want is that when I update the columns of example table one, to automatically be updated at the columns of the table two. Sorry for my English I hope that you understood my question.

Comment: You should use Trigger- `AFTER INSERT ON example_table_1`. If you will post table structures for both the tables and explain your exact need, you will get more helpful answers.

Comment: You can learn more about triggers [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in the comments, you could create a trigger that updates table two whenever table one is updated.

But I would say that you should get rid of the data redundancy that causes the problem in the first place. Rather than storing the data twice, store them only once (maybe in a third table) and refer to the data with a foreign key rather than copying them.

If you get rid of redundancy, you have several advantages:

1. Less storage is used.
2. Less work when data are modified.
3. The data cannot become inconsistent, which would happen if only one of the copies is modified.

Comment: The idea behind of it is that I want to make an application out of this table, I can't do it with table 1 example because there are other data that I don't want to include at my app. That's why I wanted to copy certain columns at table 2. 

Example
Table1
Id
Name
Surname
Birthday

Table 2
Id
Name
Surname